# C# Accessing an array of labels from another form and altering their "Text" property

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, reference, get

This is my first post. So..critique is always welcomed.

My question is straight forward just by looking at the title.
How can I use a loop to insert values to different labels by using their reference (get,set methods are in a different form)

What I've tried is to create an array with the references of the labels. The thing is.. it assigns the new values to the array rather than changing the reference which will change the label.

I find it a bit difficult to explain it further than that.
If you have any questions, I will try to answer them best to my knowledge

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numOfPeriods = Convert.ToInt32(cmbPeriods.Text)-1;
        string initialString = cmbStartTime.Text; //Gets the input from combo box "cmbStartTime".
        string newTime;
        decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(TimeSpan.Parse(initialString).TotalHours); //Converts the set by user Lesson start time to a decimal value.
        decimal dec2;
        decimal lessonLength = 1; // Default lesson length is set to 1 hour.

        TimeSpan time;
        Test FormOpen = new Test();

        string[] periodStartTimes = new string[9] //Loop referencing the labels on Form TEST
        {
            FormOpen.startTime,FormOpen.startTime2, FormOpen.startTime3, FormOpen.startTime4,
            FormOpen.startTime5, FormOpen.startTime6, FormOpen.startTime7, FormOpen.startTime8,
            FormOpen.startTime9
        };

        if (cmbLessonLength.Text != "") //If the combo box "cmbLessonLength" is not empty, use that value instead of the default lesson lenght.
        {
            lessonLength = Convert.ToDecimal(cmbLessonLength.Text)/60; //Converts minutes to hours.
        }

        dec2 = dec + lessonLength; 
        time = TimeSpan.FromHours(Double.Parse(dec2.ToString()));
        newTime = time.ToString();

        if (newTime[0] == '0')
        {
            FormOpen.startTime = initialString + " - " + newTime.Remove(5).Remove(0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            FormOpen.startTime = initialString + " - " + newTime.Remove(5);
        }

        for (int x = 1; x <= numOfPeriods; x++)  //LOOP THAT ASSIGNS VALUES TO THE ARRAY AND NOT THE REFERENCE INSIDE IT
        {
            decimal workingNumber = lessonLength*x;
            decimal Convert0 = dec + workingNumber;
            TimeSpan Convert1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(Double.Parse(Convert0.ToString()));
            string Convert2 = Convert1.ToString().Remove(5);
            periodStartTimes[x] = Convert2;
        }

        FormOpen.subjectName = cmbSubjects.Text;
        FormOpen.startTime2 = periodStartTimes[1];  //IT DOES WORK LIKE THIS
        FormOpen.startTime3 = periodStartTimes[2];

        FormOpen.ShowDialog();

    }
```

I have provided the whole code, so it's clearer and if there's a more efficient way of coding this I would be really thankful if someone could give me a few tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cannot work using that array *periodStartTimes* This is an array of strings and when you initialize it you get the value of the property (IE the current text of the labels) not a reference to a property that you can use to change the labels.

In any case it is a bad practice to allow a different class instance change the internal values of another class. It is better to provide a public method used by the external classes to change the internal properties.

So for example your Test form class could have a public method named as SetTextLabel

```
public class Test : Form
{
   ....
   public void SetLabelText(string name, string value)
   {
       switch(name)
       {
           case "startTime":
              this.labelForStartTime.Text = value;
              break;
           case "label1":
              this.firstLabelToUpdate.Text = value;
              break;
           ... 
           // and so on for all other labels 
       }
   }
}
```

In this way the code that changes the label is inside the Test class and you can add all the checks and validations required with full access to all the internal variables of the Test class.

Now your loop can be rewritten as

```
for (int x = 1; x <= numOfPeriods; x++)  
{
    decimal workingNumber = lessonLength*x;
    decimal Convert0 = dec + workingNumber;
    TimeSpan Convert1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(Double.Parse(Convert0.ToString()));
    string Convert2 = Convert1.ToString().Remove(5);
    FormOpen.SetLabelText("label" + x.ToString, Convert2;
}
```

Of course now you don't need anymore the array, and this will probably remove another error present in your actual code. The array is fixed at 9 elements but you loop for *numOfPeriods* starting from 1 (thus skipping the first element) and if *numOfPeriods* is bigger than 8 your code will crash with IndexOutOfRange exception